# How to change relative path in hyperlinks?

Tags: 8, deployment

I have developed site on localhost in XAMPP, in the folder C:\xampp\htdocs\drupLC

Then everything uploaded to the server.

And now all (or many of them) hyperlinks looks like

> example.com/**drupLC**/user
>
> example.com/**drupLC**/admin (etc).

How can I get rid of **drupLC** from all hyperlinks? Because my site is not usable.

Comment: Hi @lyborko, welcome to Drupal Answers. Could you improve your question by tagging it with the Drupal core version you're using, and include where exactly these urls are stored. Are they in the body field, possibly added by a Wysiwyg editor, or in link fields, or some other way? Thanks!

Comment: @WimMostrey I do not know how to re-tag this post. I am using Drupal 8.2.5. When I logged in like admin, then on the tool bar were links like example.com/drupLC/admin/content and so on. 
It seems, that it is ok for the guest, but for admin it is broken. Administrative backend is affected

Answer (score 1):

You may need to:

1. Check the setting for `RewriteBase` in .htaccess (e.g make `RewriteBase /`)
2. Check the `$base_url` setting is correct (Should be automatic in D8).
3. Clear all caches ( Admin > Config > Development > Performance > Clear cache )

If you have inline links in body content with incorrect URLs, that's a different story, but the above may help with the standard stuff.

Comment: David thanks for helping me. But there is no RewriteBase in .htaccess. C:\xampp\htdocs\drupLC\.htaccess
and also not in : C:\xampp\htdocs\drupLC\sites\default\files\.htaccess
There is no $base_url in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupLC\sites\default\settings.php

I do not know neither how to clear all cache. Because Drupal wins over my patience. Nothing works like should. I try to add RewriteBase / somewhere. 
By the way: I checked database for occurence "drupLC" and I have found hundreds hits in cache tables. This is what you mean?

Comment: I searched localhost, while I uploaded these files recently.

Comment: RewriteBase is in the default D8 .htaccess file. If using Apache, check you have that file https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.4.x/.htaccess#L119 maybe it wasn't uploaded, or has been rewritten by your host. Answer updated for cache clear.

Comment: OK. I uncommented #RewriteBase /, and I have RewriteBase / only. 
Uploaded .htaccess, reloaded site, but nothing significant happened. 
Should I empty all tables with the name cashe? watchdog is full of drupLC too... wait I see your edits...

Comment: Clear the caches as well, might just be that admin > config > development > performance

Comment: So, cash is cleared, but I have lost all css styling (I suppose). While in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupLC\sites\default\files\css  there are many css sheets, which contain many "drupLC".
It seems, that drupLC is removed from hyperlinks like desired. But whole page is ugly. Do you have a remedy?
By the way I can not find $base_url anywhere in settings.php (whole path is above)

Comment: I replaced all occurences of "drupLC/" in all css sheets, uploaded, failed... Drupal is pure despair for me. Every click is shed with blood. Thanx David for your effort

Comment: Yeah hard to say without knowing more about how you got the "drupLC" in your codebase to start with, anyway, hopefully that helps, good luck

Comment: Finally, I completely removed database, deployed once more, cleared cache, let the .htaccess intact (RewriteBase /) and surprisingly it works fine.No idea, what I did wrong before. You deserve upvote :-) thanx again...

Comment: @lyborko, cool glad you got it working. If the answer helped solve the issue, you can also mark it as accepted, thx. All the best with the project